# MUI 5 Autocomplete filtered options count

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

How to get the count of the filtered options from MUI 5 `Autocomplete` component? (without changing the default behaviour of the prop `filterOptions`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a wrapper of `filterOptions` callback by using `createFilterOption` to create a default value like [the one](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/c3fc8b881aee6c0ca85718550e7d60a4c2b9d1c1/packages/mui-base/src/AutocompleteUnstyled/useAutocomplete.js#L64) that is used internally and add your additional code to check for the result length:

```
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Autocomplete, { createFilterOptions } from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';

const _filterOptions = createFilterOptions();

export default function ComboBox() {
  const [optionCount, setOptionCount] = React.useState(0);
  const filterOptions = React.useCallback((options, state) => {
    const results = _filterOptions(options, state);

    if (optionCount !== results.length) {
      setOptionCount(results.length);
    }

    return results;
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Typography mb={2}>Option count: {optionCount}</Typography>
      <Autocomplete
        filterOptions={filterOptions}
        options={top100Films}
        sx={{ width: 300 }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 2):

I was using the solution propsed by NearHuscarl and although it worked like a charm, there was this warning from react that kept popping up

```
Cannot update a component while rendering a different component
```

So what I did was to use a ref to store the count

```
const currentViewOptions = useRef(0);


// Instead of: setOptionCount(results.length);
currentViewOptions.current = results.length;
```

And it worked like a charm. In case anyone comes here with the same problem.